# how to print list in python passing variables

Tags: python-3.x

```py
A = "hey"
b = {'"type": "push", "top": "A"'}
print(b)
```

outputs

```
{'"type": "push", "top": "A"'}
```

But the output I wanted is:

```
{"type": "push", "top": "hey"}
```

Notice that  I need the "" around hey.

Comment: use `A` instead of `"A"`. the latter is a string literal,  NOT your variable name A

Comment: @DavidZemens Read the Note

Comment: Are you trying to manually construct a JSON string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
A = "hey"

b = {'"type": "push", "top":"'+A+'"'} 

print(b)
```

---

Output
`{'"type": "push", "top":"hey"'}`

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside quotes such as "" or '' will br treated as strings in python so to get rid off that we need to remove the double quotes.

Example:

```
version="python3"

temp="version"

ex_temp=version
```

temp will hold the "version" string where as ex_temp wil hold the "python3"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the comment that you need quotes around the output. also noting that `b` is not any sort of list, it's a set with a single element, which is the string enclosed by the single quotes.

But assuming that holds, then you simply need to define your string so that it includes the quotation marks.

```
A = "\"hey\""  # escaped quotation marks
```

Then you can use an f-string in your `set`:

```
b = {f'"type": "push", "top": {A}'}
```

And then:

```
>>> print(b)
{'"type": "push", "top": "hey"'}
```

If you expect `{"type": "push", "top": "hey"}` output, then you need to define your `A = "hey"` (without escaped quotes) and then define your set properly rather than as a single-quote-enclosed string:

```
>>> A = "hey"
>>> b = {"type": "push", "top": f'{A}'}
>>> print(b)
{'type': 'push', 'top': 'hey'}
```